Select previous and next rows from R dataframe where condition is true
I have a dataframe with a condition column. I would like to know the indices of all rows that are TRUE and the next and previous rows (without duplicates).
For example, if my dataframe is df = data.frame(x=c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)) then I would like c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8).
Of course which(df$x) will return c(1, 5, 6, 8). I would like to add 2 because it follows row 1, which is TRUE, 4 because it precedes row 5, 7 because it follows row 6 precedes and row 8.
Performance is a concern as the dataframe could be very large. I would prefer base R solutions if possible to avoid dependencies. The first and last values are always the same if that is relevant.

You can use the dplyr lead() and lag() function to help. Basically find rows that are true, or where the previous value is true, or the next value is true.
library(dplyr)
which(with(df, x | lead(x, 1, FALSE) | lag(x, 1, FALSE)))
# [1] 1 2 4 5 6 7 8


Thanks for that. That looks nice and simple. This will end up in someone else's package so dependencies may be a problem and would like to avoid those if possible.

Could use a base R variation like: df$x_lead = c(df$x[2:nrow(df)], NA);   df$x_lag = c(NA, df$x[1:(nrow(df)-1)]);   which(with(df, x | x_lead | x_lag))
